# Save post type order sorted with jQuery sortable in Wordpress Admin

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I have a custom post type called 'items' that I would like to set a global order for, that a user can set, to determine the order in which the items post type renders throughout the site. I have a theme settings section in the Wordpress admin where I set these kinds of global values.

I have it working so that you can sort them using jQuery UI's sortable(), but I don't know how to save the order that gets set when you drag and drop. When I save, the page reloads and the order gets reset and the list in the admin renders with the default order.

Any guidance on how to approach this would be greatly appreciated.

```php
<ul id="sortable-items">
    <?php 
        $args = array(  
            'post_type' => 'items',
            'post_status' => 'publish',
        );

        $loop = new WP_Query( $args ); 

        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); 
        ?>

                <li><?php the_title() ?></li>

        <?php
        endwhile;

        wp_reset_postdata(); 
    ?>      
</ul>
```

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(function () {
        $("#sortable-items").sortable();
        $("#sortable-items").disableSelection();
    });    
});
```

Comment: You can post the new order in the `update` callback. See more: https://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/

Answer (score 0):

I did find a plugin option - https://wordpress.org/plugins/post-types-order/

Would still be nice to know how to do this without a plugin if anyone has thoughts.